# Add numbers and strings without the "+" sign

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, operators, sitecore

Okay so our sitecore cms has a "feature" that takes the "+" sign (addition operator) and removes it from my javascript script block before page load.

I asked a few people if there is a work around and from what I have heard is:

1. refactor js to work without the "+" sign. (really dont know what that means.. still googling)
2. For math: subtract a negative
3. For Strings: join two arrays.

Is there a easy way to accomplish this? Or am I doomed for the next few hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For numbers:

```
function add(a,b){
    return a-(-b);
}

add(5, 7);   //12
```

For strings:

```
function concat(a,b){
    return a.concat(b);
}

concat("Foo", "bar");    //"Foobar"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Nice examples too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str1 = "".concat("Welcome ","To ","Javascript");
document.write(str1);
</script>
```

---

EDIT: Btw the better option would be to fix the code in the cms. Can you provide the code which removes `+` signs from js?

Comment: No. I do not have access to that. I am just a front end dev here. Usually I would get the shared instance and build locally on my machine and deploy and not have to worry about any workarounds. But since I am building a single page on a current site they said to use the CMS. Which is more for maintaining content but has the abitlity to add HTML CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're pushing JavaScript in through the Rich Text Editor as it's unlikely that a rendering issue so fundamental exists within the CMS. In which case you probably want to look for a more robust solution from your CMS dev. A flat text field that can be used to reference an add-hoc static JS file may be a more sensible way to address your issue without requiring the JS hack, and without exposing your code through the brittle editor that is only going to break it later anyway.